# How to show submenu when maximum height is set for the parent ul and overflow property is hidden?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am using a horizontal navigation menu with drop down like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/DNS4j/

When I have a long list of parent items or when the window size it less, the parent items breaks into two rows. In that case, I am unable to click on any of the submenus because when I move the cursor it gets hidden.

In order to troubleshoot it, i added following properties also,

```
 .menu ul {
    max-height:50px; 
    overflow:hidden;
  }
```

But then, its not at all showing the submenus, because they get hidden inside the parent. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: nobody knows the answer?